# Can't import Java.util.arraylist

Tags: java, import, importerror

I've done everything but i just don't know why it is not even accepting it...this is my code i think that it doesnt have nothing to do with it but ill send it anyways. Any help is appreciated!

```
public class Exercicio2 {
    public static String mcaracteres(String[] array) {
        int maxLength = 0;
        String maiscaracteres = null;
        for (String s : array) {
            if (s.length() > maxLength) {
                maxLength = s.length();
                maiscaracteres = s;
            }
        }
        return maiscaracteres;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] array = new String[10];
        System.out.println("Insira 10 linhas");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scn.nextLine();
            if (array[i].equals("")) break;
        }
        int choice = 0;
        while (choice != 6)   {
            System.out.println(".......................MENU........................");
            System.out.print("Opcao: ");
            choice = scn.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            if (choice > 6 || choice < 0) {
                System.out.println("Escolha invalida.Tente uma opcao entre 1 e 6");
            }
            if (choice == 1) {
;                   String maiscaracteres = mcaracteres(array);
                      System.out.format("Linha com mais caracteres: '%s'\n", maiscaracteres);
            }
            else if (choice == 4) {
                System.out.println("Insira a linha que deseja verificar");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String verify = sc.next();
                if (array.contains(verify))
                    System.out.println(verify + " já existe.");
                else {
                    System.out.println("A linha ainda nao existe");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but i'm new to java and i'm trying to figure it out little by little

Comment: There's now ArrayList in the supplied code. Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: i get it on contain because the import turns into a comment when i write it on code @JustanotherJavaprogrammer

Comment: You know most IDE's help you wth the import. Do you import java.util.ArrayList?

Comment: What do you mean? I use intelij @JustanotherJavaprogrammer

Comment: If you’re getting an error with an `import` statement, it probably would be helpful to edit your question and show us that statement.

Comment: btw: upper and lower case are important for imports! it's `java.util.ArrayList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is not an import. You are calling contains() on an array and not on a list. Please replace

```
array.contains(verify)
```

with

```
Arrays.asList(array).contains(verify)
```

and you should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Your example code has two main flaws and will not compile:

1. it does not `import java.util.Scanner;` on top
2. `array` is - as the name correctly says - an array. Arrays don't have the method `contains`, maybe you wanted to use an `java.util.ArrayList` instead?

But for the second flaw there is also a "cheap" solution, you can convert the array to a list just for the call of the `contains`. No good performance, don't do this for real software, but for your example it could work:
`if (Arrays.asList(array).contains(verify))`

You have to add another import to use `Arrays`: `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: And now try to use an `ArrayList` instead of `String[] array = new String[10];` ;)